# 404 blog url's delivering 403 status

Tags: 7

I have a blog set up on my site, when I visit a page it delivers a 200 as it should, however when I visit a page that should not be there, it delivers a 403.

Example:

domain.com/blog/good-url/ = 200

domain.com/blog/bad-url/ = 403

The second example should be delivering a 404, any ideas where this could be coming from?

Comment: Did you ever change the default 404 page? You could have accidentally set it to a page that is not available to anonymous users. Have you updated your htaccess with any 404 page rules? Check that all 404 pages are accessible to anon users.

Comment: Thanks Chris, The 404 page works for other URL's that are not in the /blog/ directory. So the 404 page works & is properly set.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the source code of the *blog* module, it appears that the path `/blog/<somestring>` is sort of *reserved* for the blog module itself.

**Problem:**

The pattern based aliases created when creating a new blog node seem to take precedence over those internal paths so if your URL alias pattern is `blog/[node:title]`, you are shown the expected blog node as long as it exists.

Once the blog node is deleted and the alias is deleted with it, `/blog/<somestring>` means "do whatever path `<somestring>` does in the blog module" which results in a `403 Forbidden` error rather than the expected `404 Not Found` error.

**Solution:**

The only solution I found is to use a different URL alias pattern such as `blogs/[node:title]` which avoids the problem.

**Tip:**

Use the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module to let the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module create redirects when changing URL aliases. It also helps to keep track of those redirects so you can see which redirect URLs still receive traffic and which could be deleted.